# What free scientific measures of political orientation are available?

Tags: political-spectrum

All items need to be freely available and the results using questionnaire should have been published in an appropriate journal (e.g. a political science journal).

I'm looking for tests that can be administered to individuals. Ideally they'd be tests that have been shown to have good reliability/validity.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you asking for results that give information about political orientation of a specific country at a specific time or a test you can take/administer?

Comment: Just edited OP to clarify that.

Comment: Obligatory DW-Nominate nomination. It's very in vogue.